# How can i resolve the resultset of the filtered query into temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to store the resultset of the given union all join query into a temporary table

```
DECLARE @no_of_days INT = 2
DECLARE @xxx DATETIME = '2009-11-04'

SELECT *
FROM   source_price_curve
WHERE  maturity_date >= DATEADD(DAY, -1 * @no_of_days, @xxx) AND maturity_date < @xxx
UNION ALL 
SELECT *
FROM   source_price_curve
WHERE  maturity_date <= DATEADD(DAY, 1 * @no_of_days, @xxx) AND maturity_date > @xxx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temp table insert has to be in the first select.

Here's a Demo on [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f0523/3/0).

```
DECLARE @no_of_days INT = 2
DECLARE @xxx DATETIME = '2009-11-04'

SELECT * into #Temp
FROM   source_price_curve
WHERE  maturity_date >= DATEADD(DAY, -1 * @no_of_days, @xxx) AND maturity_date < @xxx
UNION ALL 
SELECT *
FROM   source_price_curve
WHERE  maturity_date <= DATEADD(DAY, 1 * @no_of_days, @xxx) AND maturity_date > @xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
Insert Into #Temp
SELECT *
FROM   source_price_curve
WHERE  maturity_date >= DATEADD(DAY, -1 * @no_of_days, @xxx) AND maturity_date < @xxx
UNION ALL 
SELECT *
FROM   source_price_curve
WHERE  maturity_date <= DATEADD(DAY, 1 * @no_of_days, @xxx) AND maturity_date > @xxx
```